# Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "," (24:9) in Async and await

Tags: async-await, react-redux, react-typescript

Recently i have started learning React with Typescript. I am trying to write actions with async and await. but it showing error `Unexpected token, expected "," (24:9)`

index.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { ActionTypes } from "./types"

export interface ToDo {
  company_name: string,
  created_at: Date,
  description: string,
  featured: boolean,
    hashid: string,
    location: string,
    remote: boolean,
    term: null,
    title: string,
    updated_at: string,
    url: string
}

export interface FetchTodoActions{
  type: ActionTypes.fetchTodos,
  payload: ToDo[]
}
export const fetchTodos = ({
  return async(dispatch:Dispatch)=> {
     const response = await axios.get<ToDo[]>('https://codepen.io/jobs.json');
      dispatch<FetchTodoActions>({
      type: ActionTypes.fetchTodos,
      payload: response.data
    })
  }
})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.8.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.8.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.5",
    "axios": "0.19.1",
    "react": "16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "16.8.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.2",
    "typescript": "3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "browsers": [">0.25%", "not ie 11", "not op_mini all"]
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
  },
  "browserslist": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not ie <= 11", "not op_mini all"]
}
```

I am sharing link for codesandbox which i have implemented:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-river-bpc6y

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change syntax as below , return function instead of object :

```
export const fetchTodos = (()=>{
  return async(dispatch:Dispatch)=> {
     const response = await axios.get<ToDo[]>('https://codepen.io/jobs.json');
      dispatch<FetchTodoActions>({
      type: ActionTypes.fetchTodos,
      payload: response.data
    })
  }
})
```

if you want to use object function , the syntax as below :

```
export const testing = {
  async dispatch (){


    return "dispatch"
  }

}

async function call(){

  let info = await testing.dispatch();
  console.info({info})
}

call();
```

Comment: Thank you , its working fine. but may i know the reason , why its not accepted when i returning object?

Comment: if you want to use object, the syntax like as below :

export const testing = {
  async dispatch (){


    return "dispatch"
  }

}

async function call(){

  let info = await testing.dispatch();
  console.info({info})
}

call();